# Unable to connect to L2TP server

Tags: network, catalina, vpn

I'm currently running Catalina, 10.15.4, and have been unsuccessful in connecting to an L2TP server set up on a Windows Server machine. Two other Mac laptops, one on my own network and one at a different location, are able to connect to the L2TP server without any problems. also on my network, my Android phone and another Windows machine are both able to connect to the server as well. Attempts to connect via this machine yields a

```
The L2TP-VPN server did not respond. Try reconnecting.
If the problem continues, verify your settings and contact your Administrator.
```

according to /var/log/ppp.log all I see after a successful IPSec negotiation is

```
L2TP sent SCCRQ
L2TP cannot connect to the server
```

also to mention, running the following all yielded successes

```
/usr/bin/nc -uvw5 portquiz.net 500
/usr/bin/nc -uvw5 portquiz.net 1701
/usr/bin/nc -uvw5 portquiz.net 4500
```

any suggestions?